# Azure DevOps Server - cost to upgrade from 2019 to 2020

Tags: azure-devops-server

We have an on-premises Azure DevOps Server 2019, bought as a "standalone" license (not subscription based). Are we entitled to upgrade to 2020 or is this a separate, licensable product that we'd have to purchase?

I can't find *any* pricing specifically for 2020, and the [MS pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/) still seems to be aimed at 2019. This got me wondering whether 2020 is essentially just an "update" to 2019, therefore we'd be entitled to install it?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the [release notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-2020-rc1-release-date-june-30-2020) it's an upgrade, but probably best to reach out to your Account Manager or sales rep to confirm!

Comment: Thanks. That article certainly seems to suggest that it's an update. Another aspect to this is that our software dev team will soon be upgrading from Visual Studio 2019 to 2022. When we purchased VS2019 (standalone, not subscription) these included a DevOps server license and CALs. I wonder if these are perpetual, i.e. will we still be licensed to use DevOps once we move to VS2022?